# How to include only part of markdown in jade and markdown-it

Tags: pug, yaml, markdown

I'm doing a static blog with jade and markdown-it.
And I need to separate text for preview from other text.

I want something kinda:

```
Title text
First paragraph text.
-----------------------------------
Other text.
```

Or with metadata:

```
data: 03.01.2016
author: Den
preview-img: url
preview-title: My title text
preview-text: First paragraph text.

And here my article.

include:markdown-it(part=0) ./articles/1.md
```

So, how to do this?

Comment: Did you tried a new line before and/or after the --- line?

Comment: Yes. Line "---" creates a full width line in my page. I don't understand what it is. 

And if it's separator then how to include text only before or after this line. 

I write just: ```include:markdown-it ./articles/1.md```

Comment: Metadata is not part of [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). However, various Markdown parsers have included various formats of metadata. You will have to check the documentation for the parser you are using to see if it is supported, and if so, what format is supported. If it is not supported, you will either need to use a different implementation or parse the metadata yourself (passing the Markdown along to the parser with the metadata removed).

Comment: Markdown-it supports a plugins. Maybe there is a plugin to support this.

Answer (score 1):

This metadata is called yaml header or yaml front matter.
To load this data you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/front-matter or https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-front-matter

Answer (score 0):

May be you can build a solution with this markdown-it plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-include